# pivot running total in reverse order

Tags: excel-2007, excel-formula

I have a pivot table where I want to preserve the order of the columns, but show a running total in reverse order (i.e. the values decrease over time).
I know I can reverse the order of the columns and set up a running total, or create a separate report that references the pivot table, but I'm interested to know if it can be done within the pivot table itself keeping Months Since in ascending order (maybe using a calculated field).  Below is the pivot table I have and the one that I want

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a calculated field in the pivot:

[image: table]

The field YTD is calculated as such:

In D2 cell insert (change are probably needed to fit to your table):

=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$16,$A$2:$A$16,A2,$B$2:$B$16,">="&B2)

Then drag down from D2 to the bottom of the table.

Widen and refresh your pivot.

If data are aggregated inside the pivot (i.e. there are more rows that compose what in the image is a row), you could take MAX() o MIN() in the pivot (as you discovered yourself ;) )

Comment: Thanks @momobo, that works nicely.  All I need to do is then use the max (or min) of that calculated field to get the desired results.

Comment: Oh, yes. in my case it was not necessary, as my simulated date are already aggregated. Let's edit the answer.